# Constructing sparse matrix is very slow in Julia

Tags: performance, julia, processing-efficiency

I am trying to create a sparse matrix in Julia using theses variables: row, col and val. The size of each is 73141861 which will finally creates a sparse matrix with (6554063, 6554063) dimension.

I use the following function:

```
AS = sparse(row, col, val, n, n)
```

This takes almost 40 seconds to be finished. Is there any way to improve the speed?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that one can copy and paste in the REPL, including what packages you are using to build your sparse matrix?

Comment: Is there a language where the exact same example is faster? Benchmarks are useful.